# Jquery function to vertical align the elements doesn't work

Tags: jquery, vertical-alignment

I am using this function to vertically align the information regarding the projects in the following [link](https://diviunlimited.com/demos/minimal/):

```
/* First make each project-section div full height */   
$(window).on("load resize scroll", function(e) {
    if ($(window).height() > 600 && $(window).width() > 980 ) {
        screenHeight = $(window).height();
        menuHeight = $('#main-header').outerHeight();
        finalHeight = screenHeight - menuHeight;
        $('.project-section').css('height', finalHeight + 'px');

        /* Then Vertically align the elements */
        var colHeightElement = $('.project-section > .et_pb_row > .et_pb_column');
        colHeightElement.each(function( index ) {
            var colHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
            var colPadding = (finalHeight-colHeight)/2;
            $(this).css('padding-top', colPadding + 'px');
        });

    }


});
```

As you can see in the link the elements never get the proper height, but I can not find why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem was with the scroll function. The first time that the user scrolls it takes padding-top 0, but when it keeps scrolling it takes .outerheight() with the given padding and recalculates again the value.

The solution is to change this:

```
var colHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
```

to this:

```
var colHeight = $(this).height();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for jQuery to center your div vertically - you can do it with plan CSS.

I see in the inspect element that each of your columns gets a padding-top of some value. I guess that comes from your jQuery script:

```
/* Then Vertically align the elements */
var colHeightElement = $('.project-section > .et_pb_row > .et_pb_column');
colHeightElement.each(function( index ) {
    var colHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    var colPadding = (finalHeight-colHeight)/2;
    $(this).css('padding-top', colPadding + 'px');
});
```

Remove that block of code and make sure the `.et_pb_column` doesn't have any padding or margin.

After that, add this code:

```
.project-section .et_pb_row {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    /* This will center your div vertically */
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: This may be a solution, but I really want to know how to solve it using jquery because I'm gonna extend the function in the future and because flex-box doesn't have good support on I.E.